# Ncurses or command line alternative to ClusterSSH

Tags: ssh, cluster, curses

Is there a good NCurses alternative to [ClusterSSH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/clusterssh/)?

Comment: Product recommendations, including alternatives recon, is off topic per the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

The "mussh" script may meet your needs.  I'm not sure what your use expectations are but I know some people who've used it for years and are very happy with it.
http://mussh.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want a ncurses-based client but apart from plain old `ssh`, you can also use `pssh`[1] for managing multiple ssh connection from a console terminal.

Running a command against multiple hosts is as easy as:

`pssh -i -H "host1 host2" uname`

[1] http://code.google.com/p/parallel-ssh/